# When do we come out of private beta?

Tags: support

I suppose this is more a question for the community team.

What signs of strength do you need to see before we become a public beta?  How close are we?  I would like to draw some of the better posters from other communities but I think it will be easier to just send a link rather than have them give me an email address that I have to have an invite sent to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now apparently.